# how to use drush commands for a live site?

Tags: drush

I am using drush in my localhost. I am new to drupal and i want to execute some commands in drush for a live site. can anyone know how to use drush for a live site...?

Comment: What do you mean by "for a live site"? Do you mean you want to connect Drush to a remote site and run commands on it?

Comment: yes exactly like in http://www.examplesite.com. already i am using it in my localhost.

Comment: But you can use drush normally, simply log in server's console and use it. If you cannot, please be more specific about your situation.

Comment: where is the server console...?

Comment: Drush needs to be installed on that server. You will need ssh access to that server in order to execute any command. A typical webhosting will probably not let you connect through ssh and have drush on that server?

Comment: @Kevin Not full truth - you can do things with drush installed outside server. It's just a lot more complicated to set up.

Comment: @molot how to setup drush outside server?

Comment: You need to remotely mount server's storage and tunnel server's SQL ports to your local machine. Not an easy task. Not something I can reliably put in one answer.

Comment: Is your question essentialy a duplicate of [How to access a remote site using the command line (with drush)?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/64010/16495)?